# Not able to build Android app using gradlew

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Sorry for the ignorance as I am new to Android development. I just created a new basic Android application from Android Studio. The app can build if I choose Build -> Build Bundles / APKs -> Build Bundles. However, I need to use the CLI to build it as I have a custom `signingConfiguration`, and I am not able to got it to work.

This is my setup:

- Android Studio was downloaded from the official location
- JDK was downloaded from https://www.azul.com/core-post-download/?endpoint=zulu&uuid=c68b9114-c632-4d27-877e-1a374350347f
- `java -version` returns

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.70.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_372-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.70.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)
```

- `gradlew --version` returns

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-02-13 13:15:21 UTC
Revision:     62ab9b7c7f884426cf79fbedcf07658b2dbe9e97

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_372 (Azul Systems, Inc. 25.372-b07)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.4 aarch64
```

- Error message:

```
Welcome to Gradle 8.0!

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

- My top level build.gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    }
```

- My settings.gradle file:

```
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    rootProject.name = "My Application"
    include ':app'
```

- Operating System: Ventura 13.4

Comment: `Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2.` -- since that exists, the implication is that your setup is not looking in `google()` as a source of Maven dependencies.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do I need to change?

Comment: I do not know what you need to change, as it depends a bit on the age of the project. I recommend that you edit your question and post the `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files from the project root directory. You will need to make changes to one of those files, and seeing the current contents will help us tell you what to change and in which of those files.

Comment: Posted the content of those files. This is just a test project I created yesterday, using the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: For this project, `settings.gradle` is the file in question, and you have `google()` in the expected spots. Unless for some reason your computer cannot access `maven.google.com`, I do not know why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2` is not compatible with JDK 8. I changed `JAVA_HOME` to point to a JDK 17 installation and the build went through.